# How to convert image data to JPG before storing as BLOB

Tags: php, mysql

I'm looking for a way to convert all image files to JPG before storing them as a BLOB in the MySQL database. My current system takes any photo and stores it as a blob, but I'm not sure how I can display multiple formats at the same time since my code explicitly states image/jpeg.

For context, this is part of a social networking site with a timeline that dynamically generates posts and images. At the minute there are jpg and png files in there and the png files won't display.

Here's the code I currently use to display an image:

```
<img class="img-responsive" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,<?= base64_encode($photoContent) ?>">
```

And here's the code I use to get image data before storing it in the db:

```
$IMAGE = $_FILES['uploadPhoto']['tmp_name'];
$uploadIMAGE = addslashes(file_get_contents($IMAGE));
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Add another DB column with filetype and use that when displaying it maybe?

Comment: when you upload the images it is fairly trivial to get the file extension &/or mime type of the image. If that is stored, as @AbraCadaver suggests, then your main code could be tweaked just a little to accomodate  whatever image type you are dealing with - be it jpg, png, gif or possibly other

Comment: Why store as a blob? Bad idea. Save the file in a non public folder, and just store the path to the file instead.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Adding the extra column + code seemed to do the trick :)